# Issue with Refit and Polly Configuration Retry

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, refit

I'm encountering an issue with my Refit and Polly configuration for handling HTTP requests and retries. But it not working. Please assist me for this code Here's the relevant code:

```
 services.AddRefitClient<IHttpClient>()
         .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(https://api.powerbi.com))
         .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(int.Parse(2), _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.Parse(5000)), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
         {
             Log.Warning($"Request failed: {result.Exception.Message}. Wait {timeSpan.TotalSeconds}s before retry. Retry attempt {retryCount}.");
         }));
```

I expect that If I get 404 not found then it will retry a second time

Answer (score 1):

`AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` will not trigger for 404. [It is defined to handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addtransienthttperrorpolicy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks)

- 408 (Request Timeout) status code,
- 5XX (Server Error) status codes,
- `HttpRequestException`

---

404 (Not Found) usually not considered as transient failure. So, retrying on this status code might not change the outcome. Since the question do not include too much contextual information my best guess is that you want to fetch a resource which will eventually become available.

In that case you can define your policy like this

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(...);

...

.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy) //Instead of AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy
```